# Slice series based on values in another series of the same data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame sample below and trying to get to the following output. Have looked through a lot of examples but none seem to handle this specific scenario. See the sample data.

Not sure if there is a way to achieve this using `apply` or `map` but I am not tied to it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'collen': [5, 3, 2, None, 3], 'colstr': ['turquoise', 'white', 'blue', 'red',None]})

    collen  colstr
0   5.0     turquoise
1   3.0     white
2   2.0     blue
3   NaN     red
4   3.0     None
```

**Expected outcome:**

```
    collen  colstr      new_col_str
0   5.0     turquoise   turqu
1   3.0     white       whi
2   2.0     blue        bl
3   NaN     red         red
4   3.0     None        None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're on a recent version of pandas supporting nullale integers (`Int64`), then first cast `collen` to `Int64`. Then use that as for string slicing.

```
df.collen = df.collen.astype('Int64')
```

next, use the following lambda to generate the new column

```
df['new_col_str'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: x.colstr if pd.isnull(x.colstr) or pd.isnull(x.collen) else x.colstr[:x.collen], 
    axis=1
    )
```

Comment: on the same note, is there a way to do a contain search across series? i.e the output is a boolean flag if the string of `col1` in given row is contained within the string of `col2` of the same row.

Comment: @Drj, not sure what you mean, please make a full post with example input output & attempt to help SO community answer your question

Answer (score 1):

Try with two condition here :-)

```
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x : x['colstr'] if pd.isnull(x['collen']) or pd.isnull(x['colstr']) else x['colstr'][:int(x['collen'])],axis=1)
df
Out[98]: 
   collen     colstr    new
0     5.0  turquoise  turqu
1     3.0      white    whi
2     2.0       blue     bl
3     NaN        red    red
4     3.0       None   None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(row):
    if row["colstr"] is None:
        return None
    elif pd.isna(row["collen"]):
        return row["colstr"]
    else:
        return row["colstr"][:int(row["collen"])]

df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

**Result**

```
0    turqu
1      whi
2       bl
3      red
4     None
dtype: object
```